# Reach Object of XML

Tags: php, xml

i try to to parse a xml, but i get some errors

http://fincha.com/kunden/gordon/

i get the whole xml, not only the needed

```
$xmlStr = file_get_contents('http://demo-q4:gO62OGvh@de.channel.pangora.com:80/livexml/2.1/demo-de.portal.xml/query/apple+ipod?srt=rel&pgn='.$page.'&pge=10');
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

print_r($xmlObj->{product-results-module}->{product-results});
```

i just need the products please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($xmlObj->{"product-results-module"}->{"product-results"}->{"product"} as $produkt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the single quotes

```
print_r($xmlObj->{'product-results-module'}->{'product-results'});
```